# AtrributeError: Get-session

Tags: python, keras, pip, anaconda

Using `Anaconda` I am trying to execute a script written in python which gives the following exception:

```
AttributeError: module "keras-backend" has no attributes named "get-session".
```

I did a bit of researching and didnt find any clue which library to download.

Comment: Look into this [link](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/58255821.shtml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The soloution is easy. I just installed `keras 2.0.8` and the problem is solved.